# Non-divergence form elliptic operator: Positive for certain input.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

> Demonstrate that for a uniformly elliptic operator $L$ (the matrix is uniformly elliptic), the inequality $L|x|^q > 0$ holds in the set $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash\{0\}$, as long as the exponent $q$ is less than a specific negative value denoted as $q_0$. This value $q_0$ depends on both the dimension $n$ and the constant $\rho$ associated with the operator $L$.

I solved it and will soon put a solution up. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: What do you get when you plug the uniform ellipticity condition into the expression of $L|x|^q$ ?

Comment: You haven’t calculated the second derivatives correctly. You need to use the product rule and that $\partial_i x_j =\delta_{ij}$

Comment: @JackT But if I differentiate wrt $x_i,$ then $x_j$ is like a constant if $i\neq j.$

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it’s $1$ if $i=j$ (you cannot just ignore this case because you sum over all $i$ and $j$).  Here $\delta_{ij} $ is the Kronecker delta, that is, $\delta_{ij} =1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij} =0$ if $i\neq j$

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike Thx, took me a second to get it.